# GPU Passthrough in kvm, but dmesg reports arm-smmu-v3 CMD_SYNC timeout on host

Tags: nvidia, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

For some reason I can only use `iommu.passthrough` to enable iommu on my arm64 borad. It seems I successfuly passthrough a Tesla P4 into my guest machine.

[image: lspci in guest machine]

But after installing the Nvidia vgpu driver, `nvidia-smi` reported `"No devices were found"` on the guest machine. Additionally, when the guest machine started, dmesg reported some smmu errors like `arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at ***`  on the host (attached at the end of this message).

I also installed the Nvidia driver on my host machine and found that nvidia-smi could correctly output the GPU information.

My host system is Ubuntu22.04, and I tried both Ubuntu20.04 and Ubuntu22.10 for guest system.

I wonder what happened in my guest machine? What should I do to fix the problem.

```
root@thinkforce:~# dmesg | tail -50
[   54.124325] input: OpenBMC virtual_input as /devices/platform/PNP0D10:00/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.0/0003:1D6B:0104.0001/input/input0
[   54.184912] hid-generic 0003:1D6B:0104.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [OpenBMC virtual_input] on usb-PNP0D10:00-1.2.4/input0
[   54.185004] input: OpenBMC virtual_input as /devices/platform/PNP0D10:00/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.1/0003:1D6B:0104.0002/input/input1
[   54.185073] hid-generic 0003:1D6B:0104.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [OpenBMC virtual_input] on usb-PNP0D10:00-1.2.4/input1
[   54.208841] input: OpenBMC virtual_input as /devices/platform/PNP0D10:00/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.2/0003:1D6B:0104.0003/input/input2
[   54.268850] hid-generic 0003:1D6B:0104.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Device [OpenBMC virtual_input] on usb-PNP0D10:00-1.2.4/input2
[  127.924120] kauditd_printk_skb: 38 callbacks suppressed
[  127.924125] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737029.351:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1170 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  128.058433] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737029.484:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1239 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[  128.089347] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[  128.171676] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737029.600:52): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=1346 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  128.219844] Bridge firewalling registered
[  128.289482] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[  139.590270] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[  141.835477] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  159.003540] systemd-journald[723]: File /var/log/journal/916b199219734366901b8d667f583037/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  159.136629] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  160.644572] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  224.527998] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737125.972:53): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-b85ad22b-4908-49d6-a080-3d6e61e077b1" pid=3029 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  224.700728] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737126.144:54): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-b85ad22b-4908-49d6-a080-3d6e61e077b1" pid=3032 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  224.865398] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737126.308:55): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-b85ad22b-4908-49d6-a080-3d6e61e077b1" pid=3036 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  225.046268] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737126.488:56): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-b85ad22b-4908-49d6-a080-3d6e61e077b1" pid=3040 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  225.069258] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[  225.069263] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
[  225.069329] device vnet0 entered promiscuous mode
[  225.069529] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[  225.069532] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered listening state
[  225.248074] audit: type=1400 audit(1700737126.692:57): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-b85ad22b-4908-49d6-a080-3d6e61e077b1" pid=3065 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  226.602689] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000018 [hwprod 0x00000019, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  227.094879] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered learning state
[  227.667321] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x0000001a [hwprod 0x0000001b, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  228.731951] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x0000001c [hwprod 0x0000001d, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  229.110812] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered forwarding state
[  229.110816] virbr0: topology change detected, propagating
[  229.796583] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x0000001e [hwprod 0x0000001f, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  230.861217] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000021 [hwprod 0x00000022, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  231.925848] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000023 [hwprod 0x00000024, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  232.990480] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000025 [hwprod 0x00000026, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  234.055113] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000027 [hwprod 0x00000028, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  234.910430] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  236.050405] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vfio_ecap_init: hiding ecap 0x19@0x900
[  238.762895] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x000000a8 [hwprod 0x000000a9, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  239.827524] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x000000aa [hwprod 0x000000ab, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  240.960070] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x000000b3 [hwprod 0x000000b4, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  242.024700] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x000000b5 [hwprod 0x000000b6, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  243.090891] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000136 [hwprod 0x00000137, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  244.155521] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000138 [hwprod 0x00000139, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  245.220811] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x00000149 [hwprod 0x0000014a, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  246.285441] arm-smmu-v3 arm-smmu-v3.0.auto: CMD_SYNC timeout at 0x0000014b [hwprod 0x0000014c, hwcons 0x00000017]
[  293.889100] hrtimer: interrupt took 2921 ns
```

Update 1:

I have a question about a sentence that I have seen in many tutorials, which is:

> "An IOMMU group is the smallest set of physical devices that can be
> passed to a virtual machine."

However in my case, you can see a PCI bridge device and Nvidia card are in the same IOMMU group:

```
IOMMU Group 0:
        00:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Device [1ee5:0100] (rev 01)
        01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104GL [Tesla P4] [10de:1bb3] (rev a1)
IOMMU Group 1:
        a0:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Device [1ee5:0100] (rev 01)
        a1:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1806] (rev 01)
        a2:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1806] (rev 01)
        a2:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1806] (rev 01)
        a2:0e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1806] (rev 01)
        a3:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
        a3:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
        a4:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge [1a03:1150] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 2:
        c0:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Device [1ee5:0100] (rev 01)
        c1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO [144d:a80a]
```

Does this mean that I should passthrough both the PCI bridge and the graphics card to the virtual machine? But it seems that a no endpoint device can't be passed into kvm. I wonder if this is related to the problems I have been having passing through my graphics card?